# Mutexes in Win32

Tags: winapi, mutex

how does a mutex can be shared between processes? does it mean a different .exe process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28VS.85%29.aspx), you have the option of giving it a name. If you do give it a name, then other processes can open that mutex by using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking--do you want to know how it shares them between processes?

Mutexes on windows and other operating systems generally work between processes.  Windows also has another locking mechanism called a critical section, which only works inside a given process.